# Weird characters in the log file

Tags: ros, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I run roscore and redirect the logged output to a text file I can see weird characters:

```
 [ESC]]2;roscore[BEL]
```

where [ESC] and [BEL] are single characters within a small box (I could not add unicode to this question).

I suspect these codes come from colored ouput. How do I get rid of these characters?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211460/weird-characters-in-the-log-file./) by [SR](https://answers.ros.org/users/14071/sr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 152 on 2015-06-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I could get rid of the first character with the following regulary expression (made for Python's re engine): `'[^[:ascii:]].;'`.

The second character could be removed by discarding all `\a` characters.

---

Originally posted by [SR](https://answers.ros.org/users/14071/sr/) with karma: 152 on 2015-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This has been answered before. See [Unexpected heading and trailing symbols in logfile's string](http://answers.ros.org/question/204631/unexpected-heading-and-trailing-symbols-in-logfiles-string/) for example.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-06-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SR](https://answers.ros.org/users/14071/sr/) on 2015-06-16**:
Ok, Thanks. I will have a look at these suggestions.

**Comment by [SR](https://answers.ros.org/users/14071/sr/) on 2015-06-17**:
The problem remains. Using TERM=dumb doesn't help in my case. Also I did not find a sed command yet to strip these characters away. The mentioned characters are hard to get rid off, the normal color codes are way easier.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-06-22**:
Could be that the ones in the line you copy/pasted are actually hard coded and not actually suppressed in a dumb terminal. If you find the location in the sources then it might be an idea to open an issue against the repository to get that fixed.